# How do we define the orietation of a particular frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, free-body-diagram

I think my question will be clearer if I take some examples:

1. Find the acceleration with which a block slides down a frictionless slope.

For this problem the free body diagram for the block would look as follows:
[image]

which, after vector resolution, would look as follows:
[image]

Now, in this case, if the frame of reference was represented as a pair of axes, it would look as follows:
[image]

So my question is, why can't we instead work with a pair of axes oriented as follows:

[image]

Now I know that we need one of the components of weight of the block to be parallel to the slope and hence the original orientation works better, but then how do we decide the best orientation of the frame of reference (as a pair of axes)? For example, let me take another question:

2. Find the magnitude of friction acting on a car travelling on a circular path on a banked road.

Now for this problem, assuming that the velocity of the car is lower than the ideal velocity (one where frictional force would be 0), the friction would act outwards so as to prevent the car from slipping to the center. The free body diagram (from the car's perspective, i.e, a non-inertial frame) looks as follows:

[image]

Now in this case, after vector resolution, the FBD looks as follows:

[image]

where we form the simultaneous equations:
$$Nsin\theta=\frac{mv^2}{r}+fcos\theta$$
$$Ncos\theta+fsin\theta=mg$$
and solve for f. Now here if the frame of reference were represented as a pair of axes, we would represent it as:

[image]

and not as:

[image]

So my question finally is, how do we decide the orientation of the pair axes (the frame of reference) when dealing with such problems? In certain simple problems such as the first question, it becomes a little obvious after practicing tons of similar kinds of questions, but in miscellaneous cases such as the second problem, it isn't quite as obvious, at least not me. Is it all a matter of practice and identifying certain commonalities in different kinds of FBDs or is there a proper method for defining the orientation of the frame of reference?

Note: Sorry for the poor editing, I'm not that great with the script-writing part. Also, I realize that I haven't drawn the vectors and their components to scale, please ignore such errors.

Answer (score 1):

The acceleration vector you obtain is the same in both cases. (Set up the problem algebraically to solve for the acceleration vector.)

Physics doesn’t care what coordinates you choose to work in.

However, some choices of coordinates make the mathematical steps simpler.
(Some choices might lead to fewer nonzero components…. Or a simpler system of equations to solve.)
At the end, by whichever coordinates you choose, you will describe the same acceleration vector.

The usual rule of thumb is to choose coordinates where one axis is along the direction of acceleration (which you might be able to reason in advance).

Comment: But then let's say for example, in problem two. Instead of choosing the first coordinate system, I choose the second one (one where the x-axis is parallel to the slope of the banked road), how do you resolve any force to obtain the centripetal force?

Comment: @noobanomaly In a block on a stationary incline, it’s easier to choose the axes with one along the incline. In a banked road, it’s easier to have horizontal and vertical... since the centripetal acceleration is horizontal.